# Pass the Drender arguments to another function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an ASp.net project and i am wondering if it is possible to pass the Dredner arguments of the drender function into another function.

```
       protected void CalendarDRender(object sender,   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs e) { test(e) }

protected void test("what to i have to put as argument type"){ ..  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly

```
protected void CalendarDRender(object sender,   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs e) { test(e) }

protected void test(System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs  arg){ //do sth  }
```

or

```
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs arg=null;
        protected void CalendarDRender(object sender,   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs e) { arg=e; }

and somewhere else test(arg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible, use the same argument type of the object you want to pass. In your example if you pass `e` to your `test()` function you should use `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs` (the same type of `e`).